# Reactjs read text file line by line using fs

Tags: reactjs, node.js-fs

With reactjs, I tried to use fs to read a text file line by line, but then the compiler complains "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'. I browsed the internet, it's well known reactjs bug for webpack 5, people asked to go down to webpack 4.

I have the following questions:

1. How to go down from webpack 5 to webpack 4? Will it be affect the other codes?
2. Is there any other way to read text file line by line without using fs?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not a bug, `fs` is a *node* module, used to interact with the file system on the backend. You can't use it in the browser. You'll need to find a _front end_ method for reading the file, check Jonathan's answer

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading should be fine but have you considered using the javascript `fetch()` or `FileReader()` commands.

From the browser

```
const fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = event => {
  const fileText = event.target.result;
  const lines = fileText.split('\n');
  // do something with the lines here...
};
fileReader.readAsText(file);
```

From the server

```
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(fileText => {
    const lines = fileText.split('\n');
    // do something with the lines here...
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! From the browser, I copied your code, but got the following error : Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

Comment: You need to use the Blob type object. 

`const file = new Blob([file], {type: 'text/plain'});`

Comment: By the way, I am reading a local file, import it from the directory. I have used your second method, but got the following error : Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
    at <anonymous> (

Comment: Use `FileReader` for browser the second method is from server

Comment: The syntax you provide is not right, so I used  const file = new Blob(CategoriesFile).text(), but I got the following error : Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Failed to construct 'Blob': The provided value cannot be converted to a sequence.

Comment: My file content look like the following : GOOGLE, MISC
AMZN, MERCHANDISE
MCDONALD, DINNING
CLICKBANK, MERCHANDISE
SAFEWAY, GROCERIES

Comment: Even I use the following syntax :  const file = new Blob(CategoriesFile, {
            type: "text/plain"
        }). I got the same error.